# Why is this instance of Traversable for list not correct?

Tags: haskell, traversable

The below code fails the checkers test for traversable. I'd appreciate an explanation of why it fails, not just how to fix it.

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Test.QuickCheck.Checkers
import Test.QuickCheck.Classes

data List a =
  Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
    deriving (Show, Eq, Ord)

instance Functor List where
  fmap _ Nil = Nil
  fmap f (Cons x xs) = (Cons (f x) (fmap f xs))

instance Foldable List where
  foldr f z (Cons x xs) = f x z
  foldr _ z Nil = z

instance Traversable List where
  traverse f Nil = pure Nil
  -- traverse f (Cons x Nil) = Cons <$> f x <*> pure Nil
  traverse f (Cons x xs) = Cons <$> f x <*> (traverse f xs)

instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (List a) where
  arbitrary = sized go
    where go 0 = pure Nil
          go n = do
            xs <- go (n - 1)
            x <- arbitrary
            return (Cons x xs)

type TI = List

instance Eq a => EqProp (List a) where (=-=) = eq

main = do
  let trigger = undefined :: TI (Int, Int, [Int])
  -- quickBatch (functor trigger)
  quickBatch (traversable trigger)
```

Here you see that it passes the `fmap` laws, but not the `foldMap` ones:

```
λ> main

traversable:
  fmap:    +++ OK, passed 500 tests.
  foldMap: *** Failed! Falsifiable (after 6 tests): 
<function>
Cons 4 (Cons (-2) (Cons (-5) (Cons 5 (Cons 2 Nil))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
instance Foldable List where
  foldr f z (Cons x xs) = f x z
  foldr _ z Nil = z
```

Your Foldable instance doesn't traverse the tail of the list.

---

`checkers` tests your `Traversable` instances  by testing `Functor` and `Foldable` all together: it derives `foldMap` and `fmap` from your implementation of `Traversable` and make sure they produce the same result as `foldMap` and `fmap` you defined.

Comment: But how do I write the foldable instance? It expects a `b` not a `List b` so I cannot write something like `foldr f z (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x z) (foldr f z xs)`

Comment: @TheUnfunCat By `foldr f z xs` you got a `b`, combined with `x` now you have two values of type `a` and `b`, if there is some function produces a new `b` from them...?

Comment: Const is the only one I can think of... There might be some in the class for Applicative or whatevz but I am stumped.

Comment: @TheUnfunCat try look at the type signature of foldr again: `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`

Comment: Ok, got it: `foldr f z (Cons x xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)` but do not understand why it worked. Will just follow bitemyapps advice and `Don't sweat the stuff you don't understand immediately. Keep moving!`

Comment: @TheUnfunCat it worked because it is. `f :: a -> b -> b` means `f (x::a) (y::b) :: b`. I liked your trick using `Nil` in Traversable, you should try it with Foldable too: `foldr g z Nil = z`; `foldr g z (Cons x Nil) = z` (just for the type) or better `= g x z == g x (foldr g z Nil)`. Next substitute `xs` for `Nil` (their types are the same)...